# search dropdown is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the below code i have placed javascript code and asp.net it is a searchable dropdown it is not working in asp.net dropdown list and working in html . i have tried by using html tag it is working and not in asp.net textbox.Pls help me to solve the issue.

js:

```
 <script>
     (function ($) {
         $.widget("custom.combobox", {
             _create: function () {
                 this.wrapper = $("<span>")
          .addClass("custom-combobox")
          .insertAfter(this.element);

                 this.element.hide();
                 this._createAutocomplete();
                 this._createShowAllButton();
             },

             _createAutocomplete: function () {
                 var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

                 this.input = $("<input>")
          .appendTo(this.wrapper)
          .val(value)
          .attr("title", "")
          .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
          .autocomplete({
              delay: 0,
              minLength: 0,
              source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
          })
          .tooltip({
              tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
          });

                 this._on(this.input, {
                     autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
                         ui.item.option.selected = true;
                         this._trigger("select", event, {
                             item: ui.item.option
                         });
                     },

                     autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
                 });
             },

             _createShowAllButton: function () {
                 var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;

                 $("<a>")
          .attr("tabIndex", -1)
          .attr("title", "Show All Items")
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo(this.wrapper)
          .button({
              icons: {
                  primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
              },
              text: false
          })
          .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
          .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right")
          .mousedown(function () {
              wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
          })
          .click(function () {
              input.focus();

              // Close if already visible
              if (wasOpen) {
                  return;
              }

              // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
              input.autocomplete("search", "");
          });
             },

             _source: function (request, response) {
                 var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                 response(this.element.children("option").map(function () {
                     var text = $(this).text();
                     if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                         return {
                             label: text,
                             value: text,
                             option: this
                         };
                 }));
             },

             _removeIfInvalid: function (event, ui) {

                 // Selected an item, nothing to do
                 if (ui.item) {
                     return;
                 }

                 // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
                 var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
                 this.element.children("option").each(function () {
                     if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase) {
                         this.selected = valid = true;
                         return false;
                     }
                 });

                 // Found a match, nothing to do
                 if (valid) {
                     return;
                 }

                 // Remove invalid value
                 this.input
          .val("")
          .attr("title", value + " didn't match any item")
          .tooltip("open");
                 this.element.val("");
                 this._delay(function () {
                     this.input.tooltip("close").attr("title", "");
                 }, 2500);
                 this.input.data("ui-autocomplete").term = "";
             },

             _destroy: function () {
                 this.wrapper.remove();
                 this.element.show();
             }
         });
     })(jQuery);

     $(function () {
         $("#combobox").combobox();
         $("#toggle").click(function () {
             $("#combobox").toggle();
         });
     });
  </script>
```

asp.net:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="combobox" runat="server">
       <asp:ListItem Value="hai"></asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Again..whats not working?..any errors on console

Comment: Possible issues. 1. Not found the id because is not the rendered one, 2. Not found what to call `$.proxy(this, "_source")` 3. Not found the css style... You need from your part to investigate the real error.

Comment: it is not working on asp.net dropdown list but it is working in <select id="combobox"><option>hai></select>.I want in asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this part is your problem

```
$(function () {
     $("#combobox").combobox();
     $("#toggle").click(function () {
         $("#combobox").toggle();
     });
 });
```

The ID in the rendered HTML will be different from the ID that's just the way classic asp.net works and renders html.

If you JS-code is inside an aspx-site you can try this code

```
    $(function () {
     $("#<%=combobox.ClientID %>").combobox();
     $("#toggle").click(function () {
         $("#<%=combobox.ClientID %>").toggle();
     });
 });
```

Otherwise you'll have to find another way to let JS know the actual ClientID of your control (e.g. write it from serverside into a hidden field, use a class-name to identify the dropdown, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you are having that dropdown, since if you inspect element then the id of that asp dropdown will be changing based on framework you are using.

It would be wise if you go for class instead of ID

Eg:- you can give cssClass='MyTest' like

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ComboBox" CssClass="MyTest">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

then change jquery to "." instead of "#" like

```
$(function () {
     $(".MyTest").combobox();
     $("#toggle").click(function () {
         $(".MyTest").toggle();
     });
 });
```

other wise you can go for clientId even.

Hope this helps,

Kind Regards,

Raghu.M

Answer (score 0):

While get the id of a asp.net server side control then use it

$("#<%=combobox.ClientID %>").combobox();

Answer (score 0):

You can use this dependency it works properly and its fully custom you can even use it for multiple select. custom_searchable_dropdown.
https://pub.dev/packages/custom_searchable_dropdown